# How to send multiple orders to FTX or binace in different prices

Tags: python, loops, filter, binance

I have `df` from the excel file. So I would like to send multiple order in python by loops over each `i` rows on the `id open` columns.  If `id open == 0` then selecte the prices are as `50.2390` and `30.3245`.

How to send multiple order to exchange as `50.2390` and `30.3245`. (FTX or binance, `y` is lists of price) and also replaces the `id` respond from the server exchange into the columns `id open` at `0`.

Thank you

**df**

```
   price       id open
   70.0000     23457
   50.2390     0
   40.3125     23458
   30.3245     0
```

**code**

```
def goal():  
    for i in range(len(df)):    
        x = df.iloc[i, 1]    
        y = df.iloc[i, 0]    
        if x == 0:
            response= ftx.create_order('ONE/USD','limit','buy',0.1,y)
            print(response)

while True:   
    goal()   
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: what is the problem ? Do you get error message ? aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should use `df.apply( function )` to run function on every row separatelly and then you could do `df["response"] = df.apply( function )`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the problem - maybe you should do `df.iloc[i, 1] = response`

But I would rather use `.apply()` (instead of `for`-loop) to execute some function on every row of `df` and return new row (with changes) and assign back to `df`

```
def goal(row):

    if row['id open'] == 0:
        price = row['price']

        response = ftx.create_order('ONE/USD', 'limit', 'buy', 0.1, price)
        #print(response)

        row['id open'] = response
        
    return row

# --- main ---

df = df.apply(goal, axis=1)  # `axis=1` for `rows` instead of `columns`
```

---

It could also filter rows with `id open == 0` before `apply()` and then it doesn't need to do it inside function

```
def goal(row):

    price = row['price']

    response = ftx.create_order('ONE/USD', 'limit', 'buy', 0.1, price)
    #print(response)

    row['id open'] = response
        
    return row

# --- main ---

df[ df['id open'] == 0 ] = df[ df['id open'] == 0 ].apply(goal, axis=1)
```

and more readable

```
selected = (df['id open'] == 0)  # 

df[ selected ] = df[ selected ].apply(goal, axis=1)
```

---

It can be reduced. Function can return `response` and assing to `df.loc[ selected, 'id open']`. It needs `.loc`.

```
def goal(row):

    price = row['price']

    response = ftx.create_order('ONE/USD', 'limit', 'buy', 0.1, price)
    #print(response)

    return response

# --- main ---

selected = (df['id open'] == 0)

df.loc[ selected, 'id open'] = df[ selected ].apply(goal, axis=1)
```

---

And this can be reduced to `lambda`

```
goal = lambda row: ftx.create_order('ONE/USD', 'limit', 'buy', 0.1, row['price'])

# --- main ---

selected = (df['id open'] == 0)

df.loc[ selected, 'id open'] = df[ selected ].apply(goal, axis=1)
```

But in `lambda` you can't use `try/except` to catch problems with connection.

Comment: Thank you  but I have problem  at 'y' or price. In the last one  of the command  " response= ftx.create_order('ONE/USD','limit','buy',0.1,y) ". which y is  list type of data, kept  a lot prices. so it can not  place multiple order. Error shows  that "decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]", How i can send multiple order. Thanks

Comment: I don't know this module and documentation and I don't know if it allow to send multiple values - but if it can't send many values then you have to use `for`-loop to send every price separatelly.

Comment: but first: if you get errors then you should add it in question. And you should put full error message. We can't run your code, we can't see your screen, we can't read in your mind and you should all details put in question.

Comment: I don't understand how you could get list with `y = df.iloc[i, 0]` from example data.The only idea: you have list inside single cell or maybe you have value different then number and error may suggest problem with converting it to `decimal` number. You could use `print(y)` before `create_order()` to see for what value it gives error. I get the same error when I use text instead number `import decimal`, `decimal.Decimal("hello")` - `decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]` but `decimal.Decimal("50.2390")` works OK.

Comment: @ furas, sir, I can sent multiple order via loop in my code and you advise".  In early problem, I have set prices value on the excel file which is over market. so the prices were matched suddenly. but problem now i can not track id open  and replace or fill in excel file at 0 on the columns "id open". How can i do them. because i  used  the code loop as  for i in range(len(df)):
   x = df.iloc[i, 1]
   y = df.iloc[i, 0]
   if x == 0:
      price = y

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you ask - `df.iloc[i, 1] = ... ` ?

Comment: Actually, I have  a lot of row and column, so  I need to replace quatities, status, conditions for real time. so that why I use loop check each row and columns. Thanks. sir.

Comment: I ask about  how to track id open  that get from respons after open buy, fill id in the id open columns. because I use loop.

Comment: I think it should need only `df.iloc[i, 1] = new_value`. OR using `loc` instead of `iloc` - `df.loc[i, "id open"] = new_value`